# How to convert sparse matrix to dense matrix in Eigen

Tags: c++, matrix, sparse-matrix, eigen

Is there some easy and fast way to convert a sparse matrix to a dense matrix of doubles?

Because my `SparseMatrix` is not sparse any more, but became dense after some matrix products.

Another question I have: The Eigen library has excellent performance, how is this possible? I don't understand why, because there are only header files, no compiled source.

Comment: What does performance have to do with whether code is in `.h` files or in `.cpp` files?

Comment: To understand how Eigen works and what makes it fast, have a better look at their docs (e.g. [What happens inside](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicInsideEigenExample.html)) (which seeing the number of your questions would be useful in any case), and pick up a book on advance C++ and template programming.

In any case, you should remove that question here and make a new one for it if after this you still are not sure about some details of how it works.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Let's declare two matrices:

```
SparseMatrix<double> spMat;
MatrixXd dMat;
```

Sparse to dense:

```
dMat = MatrixXd(spMat);
```

Dense to sparse:

```
spMat = dMat.sparseView();
```