# Use Eigen library to perform sparseLU and display L & U?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, eigen3

I'm a new to *Eigen* and I'm working with sparse LU problem.
I found that if I create a vector b(n), *Eigen* could compute the x(n) for the Ax=b equation.

### Questions:

1. How to display the L & U, which is the factorization result of the original matrix A?
2. How to insert non-zeros in *Eigen*? Right now I just test with some small sparse matrix so I insert non-zeros one by one, but if I have a large-scale matrix, how can I input the matrix in my program?

Comment: Please, have a look at this [page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html), there is a complete example showing how to assemble and solve a sparse problem. Why do you need the L and U matrices?

Comment: Moreover, the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1SparseLU.html) of the SparseLU class mentions the matrixL and matrixU members. Have you tried them?

Comment: hi, ggael. Thank you for the suggestions and I had read the userguide. I think I managed to solve several small sparse problems but I DO NEED the L & U so I'm kind of struggling. As for the matrixL and matrixU, I have tried them before, but the userguide mentioned that "The only operation available with this expression is the triangular solve
* y = b; matrixL().solveInPlace(y);" so I'm still confusing about how to use these members. Could you please help me with that? Thank you again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you'll use `Eigen::FullPivLU::matrixLU()` to the original matrix, you'll receive LU decomposition matrix. To display L and U separately, you can use method `triangularView<`[mode](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__enums.html#ggab59c1bec446b10af208f977a871d910baf886b397626076218462d53d50eb96bc)`>`. In Eigen wiki you can find [good example](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1FullPivLU.html) of it. Inserting nonzeros into matrices depends on numbers, which you wan't to put. Eigen has convenient syntax, so you can easily insert values in loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
  for(int j=size;j>someNumber;j--)
    {
    matrix(i,j)=yourClass.getNextNumber();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it seems that the FullPivLU function deal with dense matrix class? I tried with my sparse matrix, but I failed. Have you succeed or could you please give me an example? Thank you again!

Comment: I didn't try it, but conversion between sparse and dense matrix [looks simple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484622/how-to-convert-sparse-matrix-to-dense-matrix-in-eigen/15592295#15592295).

Comment: Thank you. I've tried the methods. It works when I convert some small sparse into dense matrix. But I'm going to deal with large-scale sparse matrix. Is it costing to convert it into dense? And Eigen library really didn't support display L&U for sparse matrix? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this question was asked a long time ago. Apparently, referring to [Eigen documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseLU.html#a828ca6373b429d81f41f41429a7fd4ad):

> an expression of the matrix L, internally stored as supernodes The only operation available with this expression is the triangular solve

So there is no way to actually convert this to an actual sparse matrix to display it. `Eigen::FullPivLU` performs *dense* decomposition and is of no use to us here. Using it on a large sparse matrix, we would quickly run out of memory while trying to convert it to dense, and the time required to compute the factorization would increase several orders of magnitude.

An alternative solution is using the CSparse library from the [Suite Sparse](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html) as:

```
extern "C" { // we are in C++ now, since you are using Eigen
#include <csparse/cs.h>
}

const cs *p_matrix = ...; // perhaps possible to use Eigen::internal::viewAsCholmod()

css *p_symbolic_decomposition;
csn *p_factor;

p_symbolic_decomposition = cs_sqr(2, p_matrix, 0); // 1 = ordering A + AT, 2 = ATA
p_factor = cs_lu(p_matrix, m_p_symbolic_decomposition, 1.0); // tol = 1.0 for ATA ordering, or use A + AT with a small tol if the matrix has amostly symmetric nonzero pattern and large enough entries on its diagonal
// calculate ordering, symbolic decomposition and numerical decomposition

cs *L = p_factor->L, *U = p_factor->U;
// there they are (perhaps can use Eigen::internal::viewAsEigen())

cs_sfree(p_symbolic_decomposition); cs_nfree(p_factor);
// clean up (deletes the L and U matrices)
```

Note that although this does not use expliit vectorization as some Eigen functions do, it is still fairly fast. CSparse is also very compact, it is just a single header and about thirty `.c` files with no external dependencies. Easy to incorporate in any C++ project. There is no need to actually include all of Suite Sparse.